# Talking to USB devices without WinUSB driver in C#

Tags: c#, uwp, usb

All documentation regarding USB access in UWP application always assumes that WinUSB driver is used. The first step is to install WinUSB driver, only then one can use Windows.Devices.Usb namespace functions with USB device.

I am trying to access an USB device **without** WinUSB driver because this device comes with its own driver. **Does this mean that now I cannot use Windows.Devices.Usb namespace functions?** Or WinUSB driver is just a generic USB driver which can be easily substituted by specific USB device driver if it is available, and I can use Windows.Devices.Usb namespace functions if USB device has its own driver?

Comment: Not all the USB drivers are the same.  Some will work with the generic Windows Driver and other only will work with their own driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am trying to access an USB device without WinUSB driver because this device comes with its own driver. Does this mean that now I cannot use Windows.Devices.Usb namespace functions?

Yes, you can not use [Windows.Devices.Usb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Devices.Usb) if the device driver is not Winusb.sys. See the official document [What are the limitations of the namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/writing-usb-device-companion-apps-for-microsoft-store#what-are-the-limitations-of-the-namespace).